# French speaker here — How to pronounce "r" and "l"?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels, consonants

I'm a French speaker and actually I have some problems with the sounds *l* , *r* and *o* in *lawyer*. Do you have any advice for me on how to place the tongue and so on?

Comment: Just to clarify - is it any particular form of English that you want advice on?  I speak with an Urban North Island New Zealand accent; and my pronunciation of "lawyer" differs considerably from that of most Americans.  I suspect there'll be lots of variation in pronunciation within the United Kingdom too.  So please clarify, if possible, which accent you're trying to emulate.

Comment: part duplicate: [Pronunciation of “r”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13984/pronunciation-of-r)

Answer (score 4):

You might try looking at the videos and animations at [Phonetics: The Sounds of American English](http://www.uiowa.edu/~acadtech/phonetics/english/frameset.html). (I'm assuming that you are looking for General American pronunciation, not RP or other flavors of the language.)

L and R will be under *Liquids* (although for the R in "lawyer," you might do better to use **ɚ** from *Central Vowels* instead).

Oddly, they don't have any sound that really corresponds to the stressed vowel of "lawyer" - the closest, to my ear, is **ɔ** among the back vowels, although for "lawyer" and similar words the lips are rounded a little more.

Answer (score 1):

When I pronounce *l*, my tongue either protrudes forward, touching the bottom of my upper lip, with the center of my tongue touching the bottom of my teeth; or bends up and flattens in the front of the roof of my mouth, pushing against the back of my top teeth.

When I pronounce *r*, my tongue is either in a similar position to the second position noted above for *l*, but with the tongue not quite touching the roof of my mouth; or curled back slightly in the center of the roof of my mouth.

Both consonants are voiced.

Answer (score 1):

As David Wallace wrote, there is lots of variation in pronunciation. The answer to the question, depends on which form of English you learn. This link is a good one, because it has sound recordings of the different ways in which this word is pronounced in British and American English. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/lawyer?q=lawyer