# bite lower lip to or whistle your lips to pronounce "really"

Tags: pronunciation

I have seen celebrities, news readers, TV show anchors, judges sometimes bite lower lip, not like when pronounce letter "v" but in little subtle way.
And mostly they shape lips like whistle and then pronounce "really".

Which way to pronounce the "r" is correct?

Does this also depend on locale/area?

Comment: Except at the outer edges, your lips don't touch when you say "really".  (Well, maybe yours do, but not mine.)  There is a vague similarity to a whistle configuration, but only vague.

Comment: At which part of 'really' do you hear them do this? At the 'r' 'll' or 'y'?

Comment: At "r", sometimes they bite and sometimes whistle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [French speaker here — How to pronounce "r" and "l"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56438/french-speaker-here-how-to-pronounce-r-and-l) I wanted to link to [How to pronounce the letter /r/](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267928/how-to-pronounce-the-letter-r), but that one has no accepted answer.

Comment: What nationality have you heard this in? What particular newscasters?

Comment: Americans and people been in America.

Comment: Whistle is a sound; positioning the lips as if to make it is puckering. Are you detecting an audible whistle here? And can you link video?

Comment: @BrianDonovan I think people at stack are not so dumb that they can't make out meaning of question and go to verbiage. Of course no one whistles when say "really". I am only talking about the shape of the lips that they make while saying the word.

Comment: @paul Although your phrase "shape lips like whistle" says that you're describing its *shape*, BrianDonovan's query is valid in a question on pronunciation - especially for people reading the title at the questions page. His suggestion of a more accurate term, *puckering*, is helpful. It's not a matter of whether people are "dumb", as you put it (which is, by the way, somewhat offensive). It's a matter of conveying your intent more clearly and directly.

Answer (score 2):

The rhotic phoneme /r/ is often pronounced [ɻʷ] at the start of a word both in North America and in Ireland.  That [ɻʷ] is the symbol for the [voiced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonation)
[retroflex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroflex_consonant) [approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximant_consonant), with [***labialization***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labialization).

That’s a special kind of “r” sound that includes lip-rounding or lip-curling. It’s the source of the original spelling of words beginning with *wr-* but these days that spelling no longer means that, making *wring/ring, wrack/rack, wrap/rap, write/right/rite* all homophone sets in [*nearly* all dialects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters#Reduction_of_.2Fwr.2F_and_.2Fwl.2F) of English. Whether it is rounded or not depends on which region of the global anglosphere that the speaker comes from.

The labialization trait is what you’re perceiving as lip-rounding, and which presumably your first language does not have on its rhotics. Our rhotic approximants in English are notoriously difficult for learners to master, especially with the various nuances such the retroflex, labialized, and retroflex variants manifest here.

One thing you can be sure of is that if it’s being said by native speakers, they are all pronouncing it correctly for their dialect, even if these pronunciations vary by region.